# Convert String back to Tab Control Property

Tags: vb.net, serialization, tabcontrol

### Background

I have serialized a tab control's property, selected tab. I Am using two objectlists to store the object preset object that is being serialized.

```
 Dim _allPresetsList As New List(Of PresetObject)
 Dim _XmlPresetsList As New List(Of PresetObject)

  preset.TabPageProperty = TabControl1.SelectedTab.ToString()

       Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(_XmlLocation)
       Dim xml As New XmlSerializer(_allPresetsList.GetType)
       xml.Serialize(objStreamWriter, _allPresetsList)

        objStreamWriter.Close()
```

**Code used to de-serialize**

```
        Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(_XmlLocation)

        _XmlPresetsList = xml.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
        objStreamReader.Close()
```

However I cannot convert it back, this is how I have done it successfully with other controls.

```
CheckBox1.Checked = _XmlPresetsList(0).CheckBox1Property.ToString()
```

This does not work though

```
TabControl1.SelectedTab = _XmlPresetsList(0).TabPageProperty.ToString()
```

I am getting this error

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'.

**Question**

How can I convert the tab control string property from string back?

Comment: Controls are objects and cant be serialized directly.  Please show the code you used to serialize the controls (and presumably the controls on the tab?)

Comment: I have serialized a controls property, not the actual control.I'll change my question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Serialization is a two way street - if you serialized it to XML successfully, it should deserialize as easily.  Show that code.

Comment: Whats being serialized is a List of `PresetObject`. Presumably that is a collection of control states.  You should be able to set them back reversing the way you harvested the state values.  However you should turn on `Option Strict` because the code that works is setting a bool property (`Checked`) to `String`.   That is also part of what is wrong with the second: `SelectedTab` is a TabPage object and you saved the name of the control (eg "TabPage: {TabPage1}").  It might work better saving the `SelectedIndex`

Comment: That was it. Thank you @Plutonix. Did you want to submit your reply as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is probably causing your error:

```
preset.TabPageProperty = TabControl1.SelectedTab.ToString()
```

This is just going to save something like "TabPage: {TabPage1}".  Since `SelectedTab` is an object property, it cant be serialized and saving the type name of it wont be much help in determining which was selected.  As the error states you cant make a `TabPage` object from a string.  Instead save and restore something simpler like the selected index:

```
preset.TabPageIndex = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
```

I am not sure of the internals of the `PresetObject`, but I would use typed properties - in this case `Int32` rather than string.  The serializer will convert back and forth for you.

You should also turn on `Option Strict`.

```
CheckBox1.Checked = _XmlPresetsList(0).CheckBox1Property.ToString()
```

`Checked` is a boolean, yet you are assigning a string value to it.  `Option Strict` on will warn you when you are leaving VB to make this type of conversion.